# Using .css() on pseudo elements with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
var navIcon1 = $('.nav-toggle span, .nav-toggle span:before, .nav-toggle span:after');

if (iconPos >= audPos && iconPos < eventPos) {
  navIcon.css('color', 'black');
  navIcon1.css('color', 'black');

}
```

I am trying to change the color of bootstrap navigation. I tried this code but it is not working for me.
Can I change the CSS of pseudo elements with jQuery?

Comment: Did you check by inspecting elements

Comment: pseudo selectors don't work with jQuery

Answer (score 4):

Rather than adding css in your if, add a clas to "nav-toggle" for the given position and add your color for that class

Comment: this thing is not working i think i figure it out after 2 hours :)

Answer (score 2):

The only one of the elements you can modify using this method is `.nav-toggle span`, you could do:

```
if (iconPos >= audPos && iconPos < eventPos) {
  $(".nav-toggle span").css('color', 'black');
}
```

As to the other ones: `:before`, `:after` etc. are `pseudo elements` - jQuery can't access them the way you are trying to do it.

Adding a class containing your preferred color to the elements you want to change would be a way of achieving what you want to achieve.